# vue props are undefined when deployed

Tags: vue.js, deployment

i have this problem in my vue laravel app.
When in dev my code is working, i can also build and deploy to server(Forge), but when i try to go the page where the configurator component is, i get:

app-d9ecebf6.js:7 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

this.sessionData is updated in configurator and send to me  get from the database on a page reload.
I have no clue what is going on and i have to hand in some days :(

When deleting my db and starting over to mimic a fresh [Vue warn]: Data property "sessionData" is already defined in Props

could it be something to do with that?

```
<configurator @updateConfiguration="updateConfiguration" :type="this.type" 
:color="this.color" :sessionData="this.sessionData" :addFurniture="this.furnitureData"></configurator>
```

```
props: {
    test: Object,
    components: Array,
    sessionData: Object,
},

data() {
    return {
        type: "dawn",
        color: "BLACK_177_OLENA_LIGHT_GREY.glb",
        sessionData: this.sessionData,
        furnitureData: {},
    }
},
    async addFurniture(id) {

            this.furnitureData = {
                posX: 0,
                posY: 0,
                posZ: 5,
                selectedComponent: id,
                url: url,
                side: this.side,
                connection: connection
            }

    updateConfiguration(updateConfiguration) {
        this.savedConfiguration = updateConfiguration;
        this.postConfiguration();


    },
```

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Data property "sessionData" is already defined in Props. 
 at <Configurator errors= Object flash= Object ziggy= Object  ... > 
 at <Inertia initialPage= Object initialComponent= Object resolveComponent=fn<r>  ... > 
 at <App>
```

Comment: Don't use `this` in the template, i.e. `:type="type"` instead of `:type="this.type"`. Not sure if this is the error though

Comment: Okay thanks why would this matter is it not the same?

Comment: DUDE  it fucking worked! once again saved by stackoverflow thank you

Comment: Also, remove `sessionData: this.sessionData` - it's redundant and not needed. I.e. all props appear on `this` like everything declared on `data`.

Answer (score 0):

The prolblem was that i put color=this.color inside the component